# Creating multiple factories to test ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test the order of a factory. (1) I need help on writing a test that tests if the factory ordering is correct. So I assume I would have to create the factory and then alter the results and then sort them.

Also, (2) I would like to know if there is a DRYer way to creating multiple items in the Factories.

*spec/models/item_spec.rb*

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Item, :type => :model do

  let(:item) { FactoryGirl.create(:item) }
  let(:item2) { FactoryGirl.create(:item) }
  let(:item3) { FactoryGirl.create(:item) }

  it "should sort the items in order" do
    # tests order
  end
end
```

*spec/factories/items.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :item, :class => 'Item' do
    name { Forgery::Name.name }
    sequence(:ordering)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at some point here, you are testing that FactoryGirl is working correctly. Assuming that `ordering` has some sorting mechanism, you could also test that the comparator is working properly:

```
expect(generate(:ordering) <=> generate(:ordering)).to eq(-1)
# because
expect(1 <=> 2).to eq(-1)
```

if its something akin to the email sequences in the [readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences), and your ordering is incorrect, its probably a bug in FactoryGirl.

Comment: though from the standpoint of solving the immediate need of the OP, I'm upvoting the answer by @Pete.

Comment: its never a bad idea to check out base assumptions. you can always delete tests after you write them :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could give you both a check, but since you upvoted pete, I provide you the check to hopefully equal everything out. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

In similar situations I've used Ruby's `.times` method ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Integer.html#method-i-times)) to generate a set amount of Factory items and then map the objects into an array:

```
# spec/model/item_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Item do

  let(:items) {3.times.map {FactoryGirl.create(:item)} } # An array of Items

  it "should sort the items in order" do
    # tests order
  end      
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I select jed for his response and since he was able to upvote yours. (I wish I could give the checks to both). Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

```
# spec/model/item_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Item do
  let(:items) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:item, 3) }

  it "should sort the items in order" do
    # tests order
  end      
end
```

Also does the same thing. Checkout the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/FactoryGirl/Syntax/Methods)